# MySQL LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE can't find file

Tags: mysql

I try to import file menu.csv file to phpMyAdmin MySQL database this give me error message "#2 - File 'C:/Users/admin/Desktop/menu.csv' not found (Errcode: 2)"

I have tried used LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\menu.csv' and 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\menu.csv' none of them work. I also remove "LOCAL" keyword, still does not work. Can anyone please help

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/admin/Desktop/menu.csv' 
 INTO TABLE `Items`
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
 ENCLOSED BY '"'
 ESCAPED BY '\\'
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
 IGNORE 1 LINES (
  `items_items` , `price` , `section_id` , `items_description`
 )
```

Comment: Looks like the file is nnot accessible for the user wich runs mysql server. Copy the file under a path where everybody hav access.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the file in this path 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data' or the path for which ever mysql version you have.  The Mysql server has permission to access the data in that path and should therefore be allowed to load the data in the file.